# Docker registry on Linux host to store (not to run!) Windows-based images

Tags: linux, docker, docker-registry

As we all know:

***"Basically, you cannot run windows containers in Linux.
Containers are not for virtualization, and they are using the resources of the host machine."***

But what about Docker instance that works as a private Docker registry?
I`ve set up a private Docker registry on AltLinux and I want to redistribute some images for Windows.
If I do

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.4-nanoserver-1809
```

I get:
***image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform***

I understand: Windows image, Linux Docker host... But I don't want to ***run*** it here, I just want to keep in on my registry so that my Windows Server hosts could use those .NetCore and other Win-images.
I can succesfully pull   .NetCore with Linux tag but then I can`t pull it from my local registry on my Windows Docker host.

What am I missing here? What universal platform then is being used to store both Linux and Windows-based images (like Docker hub)? Do I have to use two separate docker registries if I need to store Linux and Windows-based images there?

Comment: Did you ever get a response to this?

Comment: Not at all. Still waiting :)